# Event listener in elements appended after DOM Content Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I need to listen a "change" event of a `<select>` but this works fine only on the first select, there's a button that adds more `<select>` to the `document`, so I need to check if any `<select>` is changed, I'm doing something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('select');
    for(var i=0;i < selects.length;i++) {
        selects[0].addEventListener('change', function() {
             // do something here...
        }, false);
    }
}, flase);
```

but this only executes when `DOMContentLoaded` and if I execute it outside the `document.addEventListener` it doesn't executes.

P.S. I'm doing this with pure JS cause is the same with `jQuery` and I've more control over my script with pure JS.

Comment: You would want to use `document.getElementsByTagName`, NOT `document.getElementsByClassName` to get `select` elements.

Comment: I was actually using just the `selects` with class `select`, but thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attaching events directly to DOM nodes is fine, given that those nodes already exist in the DOM.

But, as your case requests, there's a better approach that allows to bind handlers for given events to current nodes AND nodes added in the future.

You can make use of event bubbling: events attached to a node get triggered for the node itself and all of its parents. Here, i make use of body element as the parent node, but you can set the listener on any element given it is parent to current and future select elements:

```
document.body.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Check out this example to get a better idea: http://jsfiddle.net/6HqqA/.

Here's a good explanation of the concept of event bubbling: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate.

Comment: Note that document.body is available only after Window has fired "load" event. Good thing is to place logic inside a window.onload block or before </body>.

Comment: there are performance benefits and react does attach handler to rootNode as of v17.

Answer (score 1):

Don't attach them that way, use the on function from jquery

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
// your code
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Your syntax for `.on()` is not correct.  Wrong order for the parameters.

Comment: My bad, corrected it. I added the link to documentation either way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (*with jquery*) -

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('change','select', function(){ 
    // do something here...
    var val = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

This will work even if you add multiple select's dynamically

Comment: How can I do the same but with pure Javascript?