# HTML Include Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can anyone please help me to understand why my javascript code is not working when I'm including the HTML file in other HTML, whereas I'm able to include HTML code and the javascript is working on the file in which it is written?

Codes:
Initial HTML File:

```html
<img src="http://localhost/Website/Static/Logo.png" id="logo">
<h1 hidden id="name">SAM</h1>
<script>
  document.getElementById('logo').addEventListener('error', function() {
    this.hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('name').hidden = false;
  })
</script>
```

HTML file which is importing initial file the code:

```html
<script src="http://localhost/Website/script3.js"></script>
<div sam-include='http://localhost/Website/Components/brand.htm'></div>
<!--<div id="search"></div>-->
```

And, the code for static attribute:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(params) {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("[sam-include]");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var SAM_Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var temp = x[i];
    SAM_Request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        temp.innerHTML += this.responseText;
    };
    SAM_Request.open('GET', temp.getAttribute('sam-include'), true);
    SAM_Request.send();
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm including the HTML file in other HTML`, because I don't think `sam-include` is an HTML attribute

Comment: Yes, `sam-include` is not a default attribute of HTML. In my application, I'm creating it as a custom attribute, which will include an external HTML document by sending get request and appending the response to the document

Comment: I guess this is mainly because the event listeners are added on the time of dom load and you are embedding the code after that, try to check from the developer tools if there is a listener added to the part of the HTML after the code is embedded. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512016/event-listener-in-elements-appended-after-dom-content-loaded) for better referrence

Comment: The event listeners are not getting loaded even after the document is ready

Comment: isn't it supposed to be HTML in here? <div sam-include='http://localhost/Website/Components/brand.htm'></div>

Comment: I guess we can use htm also, since it is supported by both old and new browsers. Whereas, html is only supported by new browsers.

Comment: why don't you cut and paste the js to another file and include them in both html files?

Comment: I have added the js to another file and included it in both the HTML documents, then also the code is working in one HTML file(1), and when 1 is getting imported then the code is not working. For reference, I have added the external js file and 1 in js fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/Yash_fiddle/19kb0trn/2/#&togetherjs=Q3jev5SApt)

Comment: @Yash, That's not what i meant, what i meant by adding the js to another file is to add it to a .js file, not a .html file

Comment: @JackJohnson, I have shifted the code to a new .js file, and I'm importing the code from that file. link:http://jsfiddle.net/Yash_fiddle/19kb0trn/3/#&togetherjs=z6gDSKJ4FQ

Comment: So it still failed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228091/discussion-between-yash-and-jackjohnson).